# Pointer to character array

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, compiler-warnings

I have a linked list that looks like this

```
typedef struct list
{
   int num;
   int *ptr;
   struct history * next;
}history;
```

I also have a character array

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];
```

I want to set the pointer `*ptr` in my linked list to the array `args[]`
to do so I did this `history->ptr = args;`
However, when I compile I get the error "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"

What's the correct way to assign the pointer to the array?

Comment: `ptr` is a `int *` but you want to assign a `char **` to it?

Answer (score 3):

```
char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];
```

declares an array of pointers to `char` while

```
int *ptr;
```

is a pointer to `int`. You might need to declare `ptr` as:

```
char **ptr;
```

but also note that after the `args` is decayed to a pointer, it will not be possible to retrieve the count of arguments (count of its elements) by using `sizeof` anymore.